# How to create a CNN Menu Navigation using HTML, CSS and JQuery

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to implement this kind of menu navigation (http://cnn.com), when you click the hamburger icon it open the menu nav. I'm not sure if this is modal, anyone knows how to create the html, css, and jquery for this kind of menu nav?

[image: CNN Menu Nav]

Comment: where is your try codes

Comment: Sorry I have not created one yet, I'm looking at some example, maybe you can provide some links or any tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```js
$hamberger = $("#hambergerMenu");
$("#triggerMenu").click(function() {
  $hamberger.show(500);
});

$("#closeHamberger").click(function() {
  $hamberger.hide(500);
});
```

```css
#hambergerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
}

#closeHamberger {
  margin: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#hambergerMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="triggerMenu" src="http://neil.computer/stack/3line.png" />
<div id="hambergerMenu">
  <a id="closeHamberger" href="javascript:void(0)">X</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Content
    </li>
    <li>
      Good Content
    </li>
    <li>
      Bad Content
    </li>
    <li>
      Meh Content
    </li>
    <li>
      SO Content
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's so amazing simple, thanks Neil, you're awesome.. I'll figure out the rest.